# Using getNum(); Properly and Infinite Loop Problems

Tags: c, loops, infinite

Just having a few kinks in this assignment I'm trying to do. Basically I need to have a menu, 4 options, two of them accept input from user as the form of a base number and an exponent. The third one outputs the answer of the base raise to the power and then the fourth just exits the program.

I'm having trouble obtaining the users input via getNum(); I'm not too sure how to use it properly. Just looking on some tips on how to make my code work a little better.

Looking for Help:

1. Accepting user input from two different functions and using it to
   output an answer
2. Working out the infinite loop problem when selecting menu option
3. Loop back program to main menu after each function is done and only
   exit program when  menu option 4 is selected

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       int option = 0;
       do
       {
           loadMenu();
               while (option<1 || option>4)
               {
                   printf("\nChoose an option between 1 and 4:");

                   option = getNum();
                   while (getNum() != '\n');
               }
               switch (option)
               {
                   case 1:
                       baseChange();   //Gets base number
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       powerChange();  //Gets exponent
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       calcMath(); //Calculates the answer
                       break;
                   default:
                       break;
               }
       }

           while (option != 4);
           printf("Goodbye!\n");
   }
   void loadMenu()                      //Menu choices
   {
       printf("Power Menu:\n" );
       printf("  1. Change base\n");
       printf("  2. Change exponent\n");
       printf("  3. Calculate\n");
       printf("  4. Exit\n");
       printf("Option?\n");
   }

   int baseChange(int base)
   {   
       printf("What is your base?: ");

       base = getNum();
       while (getNum() != '\n');

       return base;
   }

   int powerChange(int power)
   {

       printf("What is the power?: ");

       power = getNum();
       while (getNum() != '\n');

       return power;
   }

   int calcMath(int base, int power)
   {
       int index = 0;
       long answer = 1.00;

       for(index = 1; index <= power; index++) answer = answer * base;
       {
           printf("%d raised to the power of %d is %ld.\n\n", base, power, answer);
       }

       return answer;
   }
   ```

Comment: What is `getNum()` anyway? Do you have the implementation?

Comment: What is this "getNum" you keep referring to, and why do you expect it to return both integers and characters (`'\n'`)?

Comment: @rmtheis No, that tag is deprecated.

Comment: You should set the warning levels in your compiler to maximum. That would, for instance, tell you that `main()` is declared `int` but doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble obtaining the users input via getNum(); I'm not too
>   sure how to use it properly.

You haven't told us anything about this function; it's not part of the C standard.

> Just looking on some tips on how to make my code work a little better. Looking for Help:

I think it's a little early for that. Put more effort into solving your problems, and then come back if you have specific questions. More like this one:

> Working out the infinite loop problem when selecting menu option

Look at what your program does with option the second time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please Declare the getnum() function before main() like below;

```
/* declare getnum() prior to its first use */
float getnum(void)
{
  float x;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%f", &x);
  return x;
}
```